# Search and replace one domain with another in many files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to search for a domain (domain1.it) and replace with a other domain (domain2.com), in many files, a lot.

I tried with

```
sudo find '/abc/abc/' -type f -exec sed 's/domain1\it/domain2\com/g' '{}' \;
```

but turns out to be slow, a long long process, as well as all the search files appear on the screen, as well as do not allow you to work with other commands.

Something faster, maybe with grep or I don't know, exists to do this thing I need to do?

Thank you

Comment: Your sed command isn't actually replacing anything inside the files, it's just streaming the modified content to the terminal - is that what you want? If you want to actually change the file's content you need to use "in-place" mode.

Comment: ... also I suspect your sed expression should have been `s/domain1\.it/domain2.com/g`

Comment: with sudo find "/abc/abc/" -type f -exec sed -i "s/domain1\it/domain2.com/g" '{}' \; & or sudo find "/abc/abc/" -type f -exec sed -i "s/domain1\it/domain2\com/g" '{}' \; & it works in background and doesn't show anything only [1] 1xxxx and with jobs -l this shows me Running or later Done, BUT nothing change -> when i check with sudo grep -rn '/abc/abc/' -e "domain2.com" doesn't find anything :-(

Comment: If you are trying to match `domain1.it` then the pattern needs to be `domain1\.it` not `domain1\it`. If that works, you can replace `{} \;` with `{} +` to pass multiple files at once to a single sed command - that will likely speed it up somewhat (depending on the number / size of the files).

Answer (score 1):

Without the `-i` or `--in-place` option, your `sed` command is going to stream the edited output to the terminal. Placing the command in the background won't change that.

Next, let's check your sed expression `s/domain1\it/domain2\com/g`.

The letter `i` is not special in sed regular expressions - so `\i` is the same as `i` and matches character `i` literally. You probably meant to escape the period, `.`, to make it literal. The RHS of a `s/pattern/replacement/` is just a string and doesn't need special escaping at all. So it likely should be:

```
s/domain1\.it/domain2.com/g
```

You can possibly speed your command up by passing multiple files at once to `sed` by replacing `{} \;` with `{} +`. Note that `{}` doesn't need to be quoted in bash or most of the other common shells.

Putting it all together:

```
find '/abc/abc/' -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/domain1\.it/domain2.com/g' {} +
```

- you may omit the `.bak` if you are sure you don't need to save backups of the files
- you may run the whole command in the background by appending `&` as usual
- you may run the command with `sudo` if file ownership / permissions require it